# read() stdout from child in infinite loop

Tags: c, pipe, fork, parent-child

I am forking a child which will run an infinite loop and do some things. Text will be printed to stdout with printf when the child is in a 'ready' status. I am redirecting the child's stdout with a pipe so the parent can see it. When this text prints I would like the parent to be unblocked.

The problem seems to be that the read() call will stay blocked even after the printf() call.

Here is some sample code I am working with:

parent:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    char buffer[256];

    switch(fork())
    {
        case -1:
            printf("fork failed\n");
            _exit(1);
        case 0:
            printf("Starting progtest...\n");
            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);
            execl("progtest", "progtest", NULL);

            perror("exec failed");
            _exit(1);
    }

    close(fd[1]);
    read(fd[0], &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    close(fd[0]);

    printf("buffer: %s\n", buffer);

}
```

child:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("ready\n");
    while(1)
    {
        // stuff happens here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the pipe is set up correctly. If I remove the infinite loop the parent will unblock and print "ready".

Is there any way I can use read() while the child is still running? Am I going about this incorrectly by using pipes? I need to do this twice with two different status messages.

Comment: Probably a buffering issue. Try `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf`.

Comment: @melpomene This works well for this sample, but I was hoping for an answer that wouldn't involve a lot of changes to the child source (there are quite a few print statements throughout the loop)

Comment: You can use `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` to turn off output buffering entirely.

Comment: @Geoffrey Both of these solutions fix the issue for the sample code, but they don't seem to do what I am looking for (and it seems like the read function just wasn't meant to work the way I want it to). When I try this on my actual child program read will hang waiting for more to be written. I want read to return on the next instance of a write to stdout, not all future output to stdout

Comment: Ah, I see. `read` will read up to N bytes or until EOF, you likely want to look at `getline` instead. Failing that you can use `select` to determine if there is data to be read on the file descriptor before attempting to read. When reading from a file descriptor, be it a file, socket or pipe, you must account for reading more data then you want. Normally this is done by sending a header with each message that contains the length of the message. I will propose an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to perform inter process communication (IPC). There is no 1 to 1 communication syncronization with reads/write, the parent or child can write as much as they want to the file descriptor at once, and since they are running asynchronously you must ensure you are ready to deal with this.

Normally this is done by sending a header with each message that is a fixed size, containing the length of the payload. For example:

## protocol header

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct Message
{
  uint8_t length; // assuming a maximum message length of 255 bytes, adjust as needed.
};
```

You can define extra things here, usually it's a good idea to include the version, perhaps a sequence ID, etc. It is important that if you are communicating across a network, this header's size is absolute on all hardware implementations, so the use of stdint defines is required to ensure compatibility between architectures. It is also a good idea to ensure the endian is consistent if working across architectures also.

## sending a message

```
const char data[] = "example";

// create a buffer large enough to pack the header and data into it
const uint8_t len = strlen(data) + 1;
char buffer[sizeof(struct Message) + len];

// populate the header
struct Message *m = (struct Message *)buffer;
m->length = len;

// copy in the payload after the header
memcpy(buffer + sizeof(struct Message), data, len);

// write the packed buffer
write(fd, buffer, sizeof(struct Message) + len);
```

## reading a message

```
struct Message m;
if (read(fd, &m, sizeof(struct Message)) != sizeof(struct Message))
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read the header\n");
  exit(1);
}

// If required perform validation on the header here

ssize_t offset = 0;
char data[m.length];
while(offset < m.length)
{
  ssize_t r = read(fd, data + offset, m.length - offset);
  if (r < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Read of message body failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (r == 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "The sender closed the connection\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  offset += r;
}

printf("Message Length: %u, Message Data: %s\n", m.length, data);
```

The while loop to read is requires as the data may have been split up into chunks if the sender exceeded the write buffer and is now blocking waiting to write the remainder. The header can also be split across chunks and ideally should also be read using the same technique, but for brevity I have left this out.

Comment: This is perfect! It is exactly what I wanted to achieve and certainly worthy of updating the child source for. I am seeing one small issue where the data received is print out a 2 extra characters: "@". I assume this is okay to use multiple times? Thank you very much, I am marking this as the answer. If I could +1 I would.

Comment: Please note I corrected some errors in the code, it may explain your 2 extra character problem if you have not tried it with the corrections.

Comment: Oh and yes, this can be used repeatedly, which is the entire idea. The message boundaries are well defined and each message can be extracted individually without problem. If you have multiple writers though you may want to alter the write to write the header and data in one operation so as to avoid a race condition where a 2nd writer could write a header before the 1st writer writes it's payload. Edit: actually I will update the example to do this.

Comment: I have it working twice like I wanted and it is working great! I noticed on the child side when writing there is an extra character at the start of the string. I think this is occurring on the memcpy line. When I adjust it the leading character will no longer be present, but the read call will hang :(

Comment: I can't see any reason why you would see this behavior, please open a new question with sample code and I will have a look as the problem you are now describing is unrelated to your original question.